# Complex number inequality

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

For any $z_1, z_2 \in \mathbb{C}$, is there exist $C>0$ such that
$$ 4|z_1|^2 |z_2|^2 + |z_1^2 - z_2^2|^2 \ge C (|z_1|^2 + |z_2|^2)^2 \;\;?$$

Comment: Are you asking for $C$ to be independent of $z_1,z_2$?

Comment: @gt6989b Yes I hope so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm doing something silly, this seems easy with $C=1$. Just start with the usual triangle inequality
$$|a-b|\ge\big||a|-|b|\big|$$
with $a=z_1^2$ and $b=z_2^2$.